# Trouble finding Jest on Windows

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nuget

I recently started off with some project over JavaScript, following some documentation. I am supposed to be using Jest for testing purposes.

The installation of Jest seems pretty straightforward on Linux using npm:

```
sudo npm install -g jest
```

However, I am on Windows, and unable to find Jest over lets using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=jest).

How can I retrieve Jest package over Windows?

Comment: It's not supposed to be on NuGet. Jest is Node package, not general-purpose package. not to mention that it's a good practice to have Jest locally installed in a project so you may not need a global one at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM is bundled with the Windows NodeJS installer so you should already have it and be able to install `jest` the same way. (Just drop the `sudo` prefix in a windows terminal).